# Subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$ as points on the projective line

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, projective-geometry, integer-lattices

I read on *A course in arithmetics*, of J.P. Serre, that the number of nontrivial subgroups of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^2$, with $p$ prime, is equal to "the number of points on the projective line over a field with $p$ elements". This is stated without proof, and I cannot understand it.

The projective line it mentions is the quotient 
$$(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})^2/\sim, \quad \text{where }a\sim b\Leftrightarrow \lambda a=b,\ \text{ for a }\lambda \in \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\setminus \{ 0 \}.$$
What is the relation between this quotient and the subgroups of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^2$?

Comment: Technically, it is the number of non-trivial subgroups. And the projection line is $\left((\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^2\setminus(0,0)\right)/\sim$ and $\lambda\neq 0$ in the definition if $\sim.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Of course, you are right. Only subgroups "of order $p$" are considered here, which are all the non-trivial ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The (additive) subgroups of $\Bbb F_p^2$ are exactly the $\Bbb Z$-submodules of $\Bbb F_p^2$. Moreover, the action $(n, v)\mapsto nv$ of $\Bbb Z$ on $\Bbb F_p^2$ coincides, up to taking the quotient by $p\Bbb Z$ on $\Bbb Z$, with the vector space action $(n+p\Bbb Z, v)\mapsto nv$ of $\Bbb F_p$ on $\Bbb F_p^2$. Therefore, the *non-zero, cyclic* subgroups of of $\Bbb F_p^2$ are exactly the one-dimensional vector subspaces of $\Bbb F_p^2$. Or, equivalently, the points of $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb F_p)$.

Comment: Thank you, very clear. I had forgotten to specify that I am considering only the nontrivial subgroups, which must have order $p$ and therefore be cyclic, as in this answer.